# Typescript map Object to other structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I have an object with concrete structure. I want to create another one, with other structure...Something like .map()

```
const Object: Icon = {
  Laughing: {
    iconClass: 'emoticon-3',
    name: 'Laughing :D',
    dataText: ':D',
  },
  Surprise: {
    iconClass: 'emoticon-4',
    name: "Surprise, No you di'int' :O",
    dataText: ':O',
  }
  .......
}
```

and I want to map it to other object structure:

```
const Object2: Type2 = {
  :D: {
    iconClass: 'emoticon-3',
    name: 'Laughing :D',
  },
  :O: {
    iconClass: 'emoticon-4',
    name: "Surprise, No you di'int' :O",
  }
  .......
}
```

Comment: You are stating a requirement. Please also try to add what you tried and on what front you are facing the issue with the data transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to get `dataText` as a separate variable and the remaining properties to a `rest` variable like this: `{ dataText, ...rest }`

```js
const obj = {
  Laughing: {
    iconClass: 'emoticon-3',
    name: 'Laughing :D',
    dataText: ':D',
  },
  Surprise: {
    iconClass: 'emoticon-4',
    name: "Surprise, No you di'int' :O",
    dataText: ':O',
  }
}

const newObj = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, { dataText, ...rest }) => {
  acc[dataText] = rest;
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(newObj)
```

As @jo_va suggested, you could also implicitly return from the `reduce`:

```
Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, { dataText, ...rest }) => ({ ...acc, [dataText]: rest }), {})
```

Comment: You can shorten the body with an implicit return ({ ...acc, [dataText]: rest })

Comment: @jo_va you're right. I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` to create array of object and then using `Object.assign()` create a single object.

```js
const obj = { Laughing: { iconClass: 'emoticon-3', name: 'Laughing :D', dataText: ':D', }, Surprise: { iconClass: 'emoticon-4', name: "Surprise, No you di'int' :O", dataText: ':O', } },
    result = Object.assign(...Object.values(obj).map(({dataText, ...o}) => ({[dataText] : o})));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school solution - just iterate over original object's fields and gradually create the new object.

```js
const dstObject = {};
for (const fieldName in srcObject) {
  if (Object.hasOwn(srcObject, fieldName)) {
    const oldFieldValue = srcObject[fieldName];
    const newFieldName = ... // create new field name
    const newFieldValue = ... // create new fieldValue
    dstObject[newFieldName] = newFieldValue;
  }
}
```

More `array.map`-like solution.

- Decompose original object to an array of entries using `Object.entries`.
- `.map` over that array to create new entries.
- Create new object from the new entries using `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
const srcEntries = Object.entries(srcObject);
const dstEntries = srcEntries.map(([fieldName, fieldValue]) => {
  const newFieldName = ... // create new field name
  const newFieldValue = ... // create new fieldValue
  return [newFieldName, newFieldValue];
});
const dstObject = Object.fromEntries(dstEntries);
```

The first solution doesn't create additional garbage for GC to collect, but the second might be easier to understand.

And both versions will probably make typescript unhappy, so you will probably have to do some additional type assertions.